# Do Google Cloud Firestore Functions trigger on firestore interactions by other Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase's backend functionality to emulate CQRS-like behaviour, where I have normalised CRUD tables that hold the application truth, and listeners (google cloud function triggers) that will update a light read layer depending on changes to the application truth.

For more advanced security, I now want to move some of the CRUD functionality I used to do directly with firebase from the frontend, into cloud functions as well.

I now wonder if my older Google Cloud Functions, that listen on create, update and delete of certain tables, will still work if those tables are interacted with by admin (via Google Cloud) instead of by users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the change doesn't matter.  If anything modifies a document in Cloud Firestore, any Cloud Function on that project that matches the changed document will be invoked for that change.  There is no way to change this behavior.